# WPF: Update/refresh/rebind ItemSource?

Tags: c#, wpf

I begin with some example code to illustrate my problem. But i'm new at this so it could be i'm missing some basic things. But the example is pretty close to what i would like to do.

XAML (main window):

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Click="ButtonRemove_Click">Remove</Button>
    <Button Click="ButtonAdd_Click">Add</Button>
    <TabControl Name="TabFilter" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TextList}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</StackPanel>
```

C# code:

```
public class TestText : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return _Text;
        }
        set
        {
            _Text = value; 
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private string _Text;

    public TestText(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }
}

public class Tabs : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TestText> TextList { get; set; }

    public Tabs(ObservableCollection<TestText> list)
    {
        this.TextList = list;

        if (TextList.Count == 0)
            TextList.Add(new TestText("Testing"));
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<TestText> TextList { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Tabs> Tabs { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        TextList = new ObservableCollection<TestText>();
        Tabs = new ObservableCollection<Tabs>();
        Tabs.Add(new Tabs(TextList));
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Tabs.Add(new Tabs(TextList));
    }

    private void ButtonRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Tabs.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

When i start the program i get one tab containing "Testing". I then click Remove to delete the tab. When i click Add a new tab is created.
And here is my problem. Since the collection is unchanged i expect, or would like to, that the newly created tab reflects the content in the collection. It should be a tab with the content "Testing", but the tab is empty.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It should be a tab with the content "Testing", but the tab is empty.

What you are seeing is not that the tab is empty, but instead no tab is selected. Since you removed all existing tabs, no remaining tab can keep the selection. So when the underlying collection is changed again to add another tab, that tab does not get selected automatically. If you click on the tab though to select it, the content is still there. You can actually see this by the way the tab header looks when it’s not selected.

Further note, that all your `Tabs` instances share the single `TestText` list you created in your `MainWindow`. So when you change the content in *any* tab, you are automatically changing the content in all tabs that exist, or will exist in the future, since all instances always get the same ObservableList instance passed.

Comment: Thank you, but now i feel stupid =) I was trying to make a example to illustrate my real problem, and then missed the simple thing about the selected tab. But it answers this question. Sharing of the list is also just an example, i'm not about to use the same list for several tabs.